# Python error when creating classes dynamically

Tags: python, class, dynamic, eval, creation

Let's take a project with this folder structure:

```
> eval
  > a
    > __init__.py
    > a.py
  > b
    > __init__.py
    > b.py
  __init__.py
__init__.py
m.py
```

Content of **`__init__.py`** in **a** folder:

```
from eval.a.a import A
```

Content of **a.py**:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "Class A"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Class A"

    def exec(self):
        a = eval('A()');
        print(a)

        b = eval('B()');
        print(b)
```

Content of **`__init__.py`** in **b** folder:

```
from eval.b.b import B
```

Content of **b.py**:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "Class B"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Class B "

    def exec(self):
        a = eval('A()');
        print(a)

        b = eval('B()');
        print(b)
```

Content of **`__init__.py`** in **eval** folder:

```
from eval.a.a import A
from eval.b.b import B
```

**`__init__.py`** outside **eval** folder has nothing inside.

Content of **m.py**:

```
from eval.a import A
from eval.b import B

a = eval('A()');
print(a)

b = eval('B()');
print(b)
```

Until now it works, creating my A() and B() objects, printing:

```
Class A
Class B
```

But if I change **m.py** to:

```
from eval.a import A
from eval.b import B

a = eval('A()');
print(a)

b = eval('B()');
print(b)

print('Running A.exec() now:')
a.exec()

print('Running B.exec() now:')
b.exec()
```

Then I will get:

```
Class A
Class B 
Running A.exec() now:
Class A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\test\python\teste_eval\m.py", line 19, in <module>
    a.exec()
  File "c:\dev\test\python\teste_eval\eval\a\a.py", line 15, in exec
    b = eval('B()');
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

Then the questions are:

1. Why my class B are not available to my A.exec() if in the file that I created the class I had imported both classes A and B?
2. How to fix it? What means make any class in my system available to be created by any class even inside a separate module (like 'eval' module in this example)?
3. There are a best way to create these class dynamically than use eval function?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Just because the name `B` exists in *some* module doesn't mean it exists *everywhere*. Python doesn't have a global namespace, each module has its own namespace.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically, exactly? `eval` serves no useful purpose in your code, so it's hard to understand what you want to do that you couldn't do by just removing eval and putting the source code in your `.py` file directly, instead of as a string passed to `eval`

Comment: Also note, you aren't creating *classes* but instances of those classes

Comment: "Why my class B are not available to my A.exec() if in the file that I created the class I had imported both classes A and B?" Because that is irrelevant, the name has to be *available where it is used*. You seem to have an assumption that scope works dynamically, it doesn't, python uses lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping.

Comment: I am porting this module from other languages, and using instrospection I could do it in C#, Java and Ruby, now I need to do the same in Python, but I do not found how to introspect the code to get all classes available in the program, independently of the module where it was defined. There are any way to instrospect the code in Python to get it?

Comment: What I need is create an object (inside a module) of a type (class) that is defined out of this module, in the main application, and this module does not know where the classes are defined (path and file), needing to find it at run time.

Comment: You’re in a bit of a pickle then, since Python behaves somewhat differently here from other languages. Every module needs to explicitly import the names it needs access to. There’s no globally shared namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a manner to get all modules loaded.

This is a possible solution:

```
import sys

def get_user_modules() -> list:
    ret = []
    sm = sys.modules
    for k in sm.keys():
        if (k[0] != '_'):
            if (not k.startswith('encodings.')):
                if (not (k in ['sys', 'builtins', 'nt', 'marshal', 'winreg', 'time', 'zipimport', 'codecs', 
                            'encodings', 'abc', 'io', 'stat', 'genericpath', 'ntpath', 'os', 'site', 'os.path'])):
                    ret.append(k)
    return ret
```

This code will return:

```
['eval.a.a', 'eval.a', 'eval.b.b', 'eval.b', 'eval']
```

For the system structure used in the example.

I think that the final solution should be based on this list of modules loaded.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Updated:

Another possibility is to go through the file system from the starting point to the last folder, as shown here:

```
def get_all_modules() -> list:
    r = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    t = len(r)
    l = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r):
        s = root[t:].replace('\\', '.')
        for f in files:
            if (f.endswith('.py') and (f[0:2] != '__')):
                fn = f[:-3]
                if (s != ''):
                    fn = s[1:] + '.' + fn
                l.append(fn)
    return l
```

And then, I can just use:

```
def import_all_modules() -> str:
    um = get_all_modules()
    s  = ''
    for k in um:
        if (k != __name__):
            s = s + f'from {k} import *\n'
    return s
```

To get all that I need to import and execute this doing:

```
exec(import_all_modules())
```

So, I will have dynamically imported all the classes defined within the application.

Comment: Now, one last doubt! How I can use this list to force to import? I tried to use `eval(s)` where s is a string containing for example `from eval.a import *` but it is not working. Someone has any idea of how I can create a import command at runtime? Thanks.